# how to hide the button after click

Tags: php, html

**applicant_exam.php**

```
<?php


$sql="SELECT jc.catergory_name,jc.catergory_id,j.role,j.job_id,ex.exam_paper_name,ex.exam_paper_id,ex.dateposted,ex.deadline FROM applicant a LEFT JOIN applicant_apply_job aaj ON a.email=aaj.email LEFT JOIN job j ON aaj.job_id=j.job_id LEFT JOIN job_catergory jc ON j.catergory_id=jc.catergory_id LEFT JOIN exam_paper ex ON j.job_id=ex.job_id WHERE ex.status='1' AND a.email='koshila827@gmail.com'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
?>


<table>
  <caption>Available Exams</caption>
  <thead>
    <th>Category Name</th>
     <th>Role</th>
      <th>Exam Paper Name</th>
      <th>Dareposted</th>
      <th>Closing Date</th>
      <th>Action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>


<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["catergory_name"]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["role"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["exam_paper_name"]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["dateposted"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["deadline"]; ?></td>
    <td>



    <a href="start_exam_paper.php?exid=<?php echo $row['exam_paper_id'];?>&catid=<?php echo $row['catergory_id'];?>&jobid=<?php echo $row['job_id'];?>">
 <button id="start" class="delBtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>&nbsp;Start Exam</button>




</a>
    </td>
</tr> 
     <?php

         } ?>       
             </table>
```

After click the "Start Exam " button in applicant_exam.php it reload to the "start_exam.php"
How to hide the "Start Button after click".
When the user can click the back button in web browser the button want to hide

Comment: Use jquery Reference https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: You can set  browser cookie.

Comment: Or you can store if the user as clicked the "Start Exam" button in a `$_SESSION` variable (server side) or in localStorage (client side), and evaluate it every single time start_exam.php is loaded. I typically avoid cookies because of the chance of tampering, unless it is encrypted (like in JWT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using sessions in php.

In the applicant_exam.php add this

```
<?php
   //start session
   if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["Visibility"] = "visible";
 }

$sql="SELECT jc.catergory_name,jc.catergory_id,j.role,j.job_id,ex.exam_paper_name,ex.exam_paper_id,ex.dateposted,ex.deadline FROM applicant a LEFT JOIN applicant_apply_job aaj ON a.email=aaj.email LEFT JOIN job j ON aaj.job_id=j.job_id LEFT JOIN job_catergory jc ON j.catergory_id=jc.catergory_id LEFT JOIN exam_paper ex ON j.job_id=ex.job_id WHERE ex.status='1' AND a.email='koshila827@gmail.com'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
?>
```

Now in the anchor,

```
<a href="start_exam_paper.php?exid=<?php echo $row['exam_paper_id'];?>&catid=<?php echo $row['catergory_id'];?>&jobid=<?php echo $row['job_id'];?>" 
            //this will set the visibility
 style="visibility:<?php echo $_SESSION["Visibility"]; ?>">
 <button id="start" class="delBtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>&nbsp;Start Exam</button> 
</a>
```

Now in the start_exam.php do this in the top,

```
<?php 
 $_SESSION["Visibility"] = "hidden";
?>
```

Thus when the user comes back to the applicant_exam.php, the visibility will be hidden, hence it wont show up.

Comment: I add this codes but not hidden the button after click

Comment: There was a typo in the visibility style given in <a>. I corrected it. Try it now. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript on the button as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button1 = document.getElementById("start");
  button1.onclick = function(){button1.style.display="none";};
</script>
```

Hide the button until a session is closed.
Use session storage as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button1 = document.getElementById("start");      
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('buttonClicked')!=1){
  button1.onclick = function(){
                      button1.style.display="none";
                      sessionStorage.setItem('buttonClicked',1);
                    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When I was logout and relogin, the button is display again. I want to hide permanant the entire row is ok. how to fix it